# mySql Relationships / Index - Checking for duplicates

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have this setup on innoDB:

```
TblUser 
user details

TblConnection
User Connection
```

`TblConnection` also has these indexes: `User, Connection` where `User` is the foreign key of `TblUser.id` and another index: `Connection, User` where `Connection` is also a foregin key to `TblUser.id`

Now I want to make sure that when adding a new row I have complete uniqueness between column combinations. By this I mean I want that `1,2` is treated the same as `2,1` and therefore an `INSERT` is not made.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly. As long as you have a unique key on both columns, it does *not* matter what *order* the columns (or combination) they are in. Otherwise, the tuple must also exist in the referencing table in order to enforce it's uniqueness.

```
CREATE TABLE tbluser (
  user int,
  details int,
  primary key(user, details));

CREATE TABLE tblconnections (
  user int,
  details int,
  connection int,
  primary key(user, details, connection),
  unique key(user, details),
  foreign key (user, details) 
    references tbluser (user, details));
```

Make sure that you specify a column list when you make this `INSERT`.

Comment: I actually couldn't post the answer but me and some friends figured it out. We made these changes and this algorithm:

First: Made tblConnection have just 2 columns user and connection
Second: We made the primary key of tblConnection the composite of both keys
Third: We made an algorithm to take 2 user ids and then submit the smallest one as the user and the bigger as the connection therefor the table is automatically ordered with indexes and no duplicates can occur.

Comment: An algorithm where?

Comment: The algorithm is done in PHP :)